# How to exclude observation that does not appear at least once every year - R

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a database where companies are identified by an ID (cnpjcei) from 2009 to 2018, where we can have 1 or more observations of a given company in a given year or no observations of a given company in a given year.

Here is a sample of the database:

```
> df
 cnpjcei   year     
   <chr>   <dbl>
 1 4774     2009
 2 4774     2010
 3 28959    2009
 4 29688    2009
 5 43591    2010
 6 43591    2010
 7 65803    2011
 8 105104   2011
 9 113980   2012
10 220043   2013
```

I would like to keep in that df only the companies that appear **at least once a year**.

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: What would your expected output look like?

Comment: I expect that in the outcome there are only companies that appear at least once every year (i.e., that there are no more observations of companies that have not appeared in every year)

Comment: please provide your data by pasting the output of `dput(df)` in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the data.table library:

```
library(data.table)

df<-data.table(df)

df<-df[,unique_years:=length(unique(year)), by=list(cnpjcei),][unique_years==10]
```

Comment: I got this error message Error in `:=`(unique_years, length(unique(year))) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").

Comment: Edited the answer above, it should work for you now!

Answer (score 0):

We can use dplyr, `group_by` id and `filter` only the cases in which `all` the elements in 2009:2018 can be found `%in%` the year column.
Please mind that, for this code to work with the sample database as in the question, the range would have to be replaced with 2009:2013

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(cnpjcei) %>% filter(all(2009:2018 %in% year))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the ids (`cnpjcei`) which has all the unique years available in the data.

```
library(dplyr)

result <- df %>% 
           group_by(cnpjcei) %>% 
           filter(n_distinct(year) == n_distinct(.$year)) %>% 
           ungroup
```